# Why is nan? not implemented on ruby Fixnum?

Tags: ruby, nan

I have a class where I use a `Fixnum` default value. I'd like to put a guard to ensure that the class is never instantiated with a `NaN` parameter. I discovered to my consternation that `Fixnum` doesn't support `nan?`.  I have a work-around. I just wondered why.

```
class Table

  attr_reader :rows, :min, :max, :increment
  def initialize min = 0, max = 100, increment = 20
    min = 0 if min.respond_to?(:nan?) && min.nan?
    max = 100 if max.respond_to?(:nam?) && max.nan?
    @min, @max, @increment, @rows = min.floor, max.ceil, increment, []
  end
end
```

To be clear, this is the behavior I'm talking about:

```
[8] pry(main)> 0.0.nan?
=> false
[9] pry(main)> BigDecimal.new(0).nan?
=> false
[10] pry(main)> 0.nan?
NoMethodError: undefined method `nan?' for 0:Fixnum
from (pry):10:in `__pry__'
```

For example, the behavior after dividing by zero.

```
[1] pry(main)> 0/0
ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
from (pry):1:in `/'
[2] pry(main)> 0.0/0.0
=> NaN
[3] pry(main)> BigDecimal.new(0) / BigDecimal.new(0)
=> #<BigDecimal:1029faf80,'NaN',9(36)>
[4] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because an integer is a finite or definite number and NaN is not applicable to it.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN):

> In computing, NaN, standing for not a number, is a numeric data type
>   value representing an undefined or unrepresentable value, especially
>   in floating-point calculations. Systematic use of NaNs was introduced
>   by the IEEE 754 floating-point standard in 1985, along with the
>   representation of other non-finite quantities like infinities.

Further examination:

```
0.0.class
# => Float
0.class
# => Fixnum
0.class.superclass
# => Integer
```

Comment: It feels like it fails the "quacks like a duck" design that makes Ruby generally consistent. I like your quote, however.

Comment: @GSP Well an integer can't quack like a float so does that really affect it?

Comment: But I can compare integers to floats, except when one side has the possible state of NaN.  So `[1, 1.0/0.0].sort => [1, Infinity]` but `[1, 0.0/0.0].sort => ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with Float failed`. Not saying you're wrong, but it's one tiny edge case where Ruby fails to work like one might expect.

Comment: Though the more I look at it, I can see your argument. Infinity is inarguably larger than 1, but NaN is undefined.  Ok. Sometimes I just need a second to talk it out.